# XmlType in Pl/Sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have the following code in SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spParseCapIQCurrency](
    @XMLString varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   --Validate proper xml format; SQL does not allow TRYCAST on xml.
   DECLARE @XML xml 
   BEGIN TRY
    SET @XML= Cast(@XMLString as xml)
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR('XMLString not in XML format.',16,1)
    RETURN
   END CATCH

   DECLARE @CURRENCY_EXCHANGE table(StartDate date, Currency varchar(50), Rate float)

   DECLARE @TABLE table(Currency varchar(50), ExchangeRate float, XMLProps xml)   
   insert into @TABLE(Currency,ExchangeRate, XMLProps)
    select X.c.value('(Identifier)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Currency,
           X.c.value('(Body/Rows/Row/C_V)[1]','float') as ExangeRate,          
           X.c.query('Properties') as XMLProps
        from @XML.nodes('/SDKClientResponse/DataArea/MultiResponse/SingleResponse') as X(c)

  DECLARE @IXStartDate int=2
  select X.c.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as 'StartDate',
        Currency, 
        ExchangeRate        
    from @TABLE
        cross apply XMLProps.nodes('/Properties/Property[position()=(sql:variable("@IXStartDate"))]') as X(c)

END
```

which i have converted to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spParseCapIQCurrency
(p_XMLString in varchar,cur out sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN

--p_XML:= xmltype(p_XMLString);

open cur for 
select * from XMLTABLE('/SDKClientResponse/DataArea/MultiResponse/SingleResponse'
PASSING xmltype(p_XMLString)
  COLUMNS 
  Currency varchar2(50) PATH 'Identifier', 
  ExchangeRate float  PATH 'Body/Rows/Row/C_V',
  XMLProps xml PATH 'Properties'
) t;

END;
```

but i am not able to understand how to achieve the below functionality in plsql as it involves cross apply as well as the position variable in the sql code:

```
DECLARE @IXStartDate int=2
  select X.c.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as 'StartDate',
        Currency, 
        ExchangeRate        
    from @TABLE
        cross apply XMLProps.nodes('/Properties/Property[position()=(sql:variable("@IXStartDate"))]') as X(c)
```

Can some one please help me achieve this?